# Bool to string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, boolean

I run my C# application which is big so I just included a part of the code

My code:

```
allowGift = Convert.ToInt32(dRow[14]) == 1;
allowInventoryStack = Convert.ToInt32(dRow[15]) == 1;
interactionType = InterractionTypes.GetTypeFromString((string)dRow[16]); //Line of error
```

And the error of stack trace

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of typpe 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'

Comment: What is the type of `dRow`? And what is the type of `interactionType`? and what line is causing the error?

Comment: You seem to be using [this class](https://github.com/Gnuns/Bfly/blob/master/Butterfly%20Emulator/HabboHotel/Items/InteractionType.cs). While most of the answers below are well-intentioned, they won't work, as `InteractionType` has no conversion from `True` or `False`. I'm sorry to say that your question is not answerable, from the information you've given us.

Comment: Look at the `InteractionType` enum (which includes values such as "football", "teleport", and "firegate"), and make sure that the values you're passing to `GetTypeFromString` are in there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
(string)dRow[16]
```

Try `ToString`:

```
dRow[16].ToString()
```

Or `Convert.ToString` :

```
Convert.ToString(dRow[16])
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
interactionType = InterractionTypes.GetTypeFromString((string)dRow[16]); //Line of error
```

to this:

```
interactionType = InterractionTypes.GetTypeFromString(dRow[16].ToString()); //Line of error
```

Comment: Unkown interaction type in parse code: False System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Comment: Please look at @Michael Petrotta comments for your question. This error is not relevant to your question, which was how to convert Boolean to String. This error is due to the use of that `InterractionTypes` library that you are using, which does no accept `False` as a valid input value.

Answer (score 1):

A `bool` cannot be directly cast to a `string` it needs to be converted.  You can just use the `Converter` class as you've done elsewhere in the code

```
InterractionTypes.GetTypeFromString(Convert.ToString(dRow[16]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(string)dRow[16]` Use `dRow[16].ToString()`

Comment: Unkown interaction type in parse code: False System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid